# Hide status bar with layout stable and maintain position of action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

Is it possible to programmatically hide the status bar without hiding the action bar?

The end goal is to hide the status bar and its content while keeping everything else on the screen in its place and **without** hiding the action bar as well, and then after 5 seconds, show the status bar again while also keeping all other content in place. Basically, to leave a blank view/space at the top of the screen the same size as the status bar.

I've tried various combinations of the following view flags:

```
private void maybeHideStatusBar() {
    int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
    persistSystemUiVisibility(mActivityWindow, flags);
}
```

Where `persistSystemUiVisibility(...)` is as follows:

```
private static void persistSystemUiVisibility(final Window window, final int visibility) {
    final View decorView = window.getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(null);
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(visibility);
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
    new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int newVisibility) {
        if (newVisibility != visibility) {
          persistSystemUiVisibility(window, visibility);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

However, the most important window flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` which actually hides the status bar and its content, also forces the action bar to be hidden as well. Is there any way to override this default action bar behavior?

All of this needs to happen after activity create and `setContentView` so `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR)` doesn't work.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated, thank you! :)